# getReference() on PsiElement always returns null value

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I get the `PsiElement` using a `PsiRecursiveElementVisitor`. The I call `getReference()` function on it but it always returns null. In my use case, I cannot use `Caret` for getting the reference. I am assuming the references we get from both are the same. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that `PsiElement` simply doesn't have any references? Try with its parents.